# Question about: Given $H_{a}=\{f\in A(T)\mid f(a)=a\}$. Show that $H_{a}$ is a subgroup of $A(T)$ that is not normal.

Tags: group-theory

For the following question below:

> Let $T$ be a set with three or more elements and let $A(T)$ be the group of all permutations of $T$.  If $a\in T$, let $H_{a}=\{f\in A(T)\mid f(a)=a\}.$  Prove that $H_{a}$ is a subgroup of $A(T)$ that is not normal.$\\$

I would usually do it by supposing if $|T|>3,$ then let $\sigma(a)=b,$ $\sigma^{-1}(b)=a,$ and if $\sigma(c)=c$ for all $c\neq a,b$.  With $f\in H_{a}$, it is straightforward to show that $\sigma H_{\sigma(a)} \sigma^{-1}=H_{a}\neq H_{\sigma(a)}$

However do I also need to show in my solution that if $\sigma\in A(T)$, and $f\in H_{\sigma(a)}$, then $\sigma H_{\sigma(a)} \sigma^{-1}=H_{a}$

Proof:  In one direction, we have:
if $f\in H_{\sigma(a)}$, then $(\sigma^{-1}\circ H_{\sigma(a)} \circ \sigma)(a)=\sigma^{-1}(f(\sigma(a)))=\sigma^{-1}f(b))= \sigma^{-1}(b)=a=f(a)\in H_{a}. \text{which gives } \sigma^{-1}\circ H_{\sigma(a)} \circ \sigma\subset H_{a}$
Conversely, if $f\in H_{a}$, then $f(a)=a.$  But $(\sigma^{-1}\circ H_{\sigma(a)}\circ \sigma)(a) = (\sigma^{-1}\circ f\circ \sigma)(a)=\sigma^{-1}(f(b))=\sigma^{-1}(b)=a=f(a)\in \sigma^{-1}\circ H_{\sigma(a)}\circ \sigma$ also. So, $H_{a}\subset \sigma^{-1}\circ H_{\sigma(a)} \circ \sigma, \text{ and along with the other direction gives }$ $\sigma^{-1} H_{\sigma(a)} \sigma=H_{a}$

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo the student solution first show that the set step (1) $H_{a}$ is a subgroup, then it shows step (2) $\sigma\in A(T)$, and $f\in H_{\sigma(a)}$, then $\sigma H_{\sigma(a)} \sigma^{-1}=H_{a}$.  Finally, it shows that step (3) if $|T|>3,$ then let $\sigma(a)=b,$ $\sigma^{-1}(b)=a,$ and if $\sigma(c)=c$ for all $c\neq a,b$.  With $f\in H_{a}$, it is straightforward to show that $\sigma H_{\sigma(a)} \sigma^{-1}=H_{a}\neq H_{\sigma(a)}$.  I want to know if I just show step (1) and step (3) in my solution.;  It seems like i don't really need to include step (2)...

Comment: @fitzcarraldo ...for purpose of clarity, do I really need to include step (2)

Comment: Okay, at a first glance I'd agree with you, but I'll think some more about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 : $H_a \le A(T) $

$id \in H_a \neq \emptyset$

$\forall f, g \in H_a$

$fg^{-1}(a)=f(a) =a$

Step 2 :

Choose, $g\in H_a$ be such that $g(t) =t \implies t=a$

And $f\in A(T) $ which doesn't fix $a$.

Then, $f^{-1} g f \notin H_a$

If true then, $(f^{-1} g f )(a) =a $

$\implies f^{-1} (g(f(a)) =a $

$\implies g(f(a))=f(a) $

$\implies f(a) =a $

Comment: Although obvious, you need to make it clear that $H_a\subseteq A(T)$.

Comment: @Shaun yes sir. It is so obvious that i forget to mention it. But in the first place $H_a$ is a non-empty subset of $A(T) $.

Comment: Also, you need to explain why such a $g$ exists.

Comment: @Shaun , sir if the set  $T$ is  finite, then obvious but if $T$ is infinite then Axiom of choice is there to help us.